# Xpages: Load jar dynamically

Tags: dynamic, jar, xpages

Has someone experience in loading jars dynamically for a XPages Application?
We would like to have some calculation code which is going to change quite often in external Jar Files and load them dynamically when they are needed. Does anyone know if that's possilbe with Domino?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a tasklet which you can roll out like an OSGI plugin. This way you can execute the calculations in this tasklet which you can update independently of your application.  That way you only need to update your update site and all applications who use that code will the latest version installed.

You can find more info about it here: http://xpag.es/?1926

Another solution would be to put the jar file on your server in the java/ext/lib directory. And every time a new release is created you can update that file on the server. A server / HTTP task restart would be necessary ofcourse.

Comment: What if you create a OSGi Bundle from a JAR and load with the OSGi console? This would allow hotplugging of the JAR?